# How to make display-text Multi-lingual?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multilingual

How can I create a window in jquery having multilingual contents?
eg. for Spanish language close window should be comes like 'maximizar la ventana'.

Comment: this doesn't come standard with jQuery but there are several plugins you can try, here's one http://www.isogenicengine.com/documentation/jquery-multi-language-site-plugin/ , try googling after some more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a set of files named `en.php`, `sp.php` etc on your server.
In each file, all messages text could be stored.

Like in `sp.php`,
`$text["close_window"] = "maximizar la ventana";`
`$text["thank_you"] = "Gracias";`

and in `en.php`,
`$text["close_window"] = "Close this window";`
`$text["thank_you"] = "Gracias";`

In your main file(`index.foo`), you could use `echo $text["close_window"];` or
`echo $text["thank_you"]` where you want this text to be displayed.

Then based on User String, or some other data, you could conditionally include english.lang or spanish.lang in the server side, according to user's language.

**Files Structure:**

index.php       //main file
lang            //language-files Folder
lang/en.php     //english language file
lang/sp.php     //spanish language file

**Example Code:**

`en.php:`

```
<?php
$text["close_window"] = "Close this window";
$text["thank_you"] = "Thank you";
$text["welcome"] = "Welcome";
$text["home"] = "Home";
$text["about_us"] = "About Us";
$text["company_history"] = "Company History";
$text["company_profile"] = "Company Profile";
$text["contact_us"] = "Contact Us";
$text["greetings"] = "You have selected English";
?>
```

`sp.php:`

```
<?php
$text["close_window"] = "maximizar la ventana";
$text["thank_you"] = "Gracias";
$text["welcome"] = "Bienvenida";
$text["home"] = "Casa";
$text["about_us"] = "Sobre Nosotros";
$text["company_history"] = "Historia de la Empresa";
$text["company_profile"] = "Perfil de la Empresa";
$text["contact_us"] = "Contact Us";
$text["greetings"] = "Usted ha seleccionado Español";
?>
```

`index.php:`

```
 //Check if browser sent the User Language code
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])      // if browser sent
    //AND is NOT empty
    && ($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] != "")
    ){ //if conditions END
    // get first two letters from it
    $user_lang = substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"], 0, 2);
}
if(isset($_POST["lang"]) //if user selected it
  //and is in our desired format
  && (strlen($_POST["lang"]) == 2)
){
    $user_lang = $_POST["lang"];
}
//if User requested to change language, ask him
if(isset($_POST["lang_change"])
  && ($_POST["lang_change"])) // is true ?
{
    ask_lang();
    exit(); // exit the script now..
}
if(!isset($user_lang)){ //if we dont have $user_lang yet, ask
    ask_lang();
    exit();
}
//Main index file contents
include("lang/".$user_lang."php");
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $text["welcome"]; ?> | Example.com</title>
    <head>
    <body>
    <?php echo $text["welcome"]; ?>, <?php echo $text["greetings"]; ?>!<br />
    <a href="index.php" title="<?php echo $text["home"]; ?>" >
        <?php echo $text["home"]; ?></a> |
    <a href="about_us.php" title="<?php echo $text["about_us"]; ?>" >
        <?php echo $text["about_us"]; ?></a> |
    <a href="history.php" title="<?php echo $text["company_history"]; ?>" >
        <?php echo $text["company_history"]; ?></a> |
    <a href="profile.php" title="<?php echo $text["company_profile"]; ?>" >
        <?php echo $text["company_profile"]; ?></a> |
    <a href="contact_us.php" title="<?php echo $text["contact_us"]; ?>" >
        <?php echo $text["contact_us"]; ?></a>
    <p>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="lang_change" value="true" />
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $text["change_language"]; ?>" name="change_language" />
        </form>
    </p>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
//Main index file contents ENDS
function ask_lang(){
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Please Select Language</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Please select language:</legend>
                <input type="radio" value="en" name="lang" />English<img src="en.png"><br />
                <input type="radio" value="sp" name="lang" />Spanish<img src="sp.png"><br />
                <input type="submit" value="OK" name="sumbit" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
} //function ask_lang() ENDS
```

**Assumptions:**

- All type of possible translation files are in the `Lang` folder.
- User input is sanitized.
- Google translated all these Phrases correctly context-wise.

Here is a **[Live Snippet at Codepad.viper-7.com](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CPGqi2)**

The Live Snippet & In-Answer code has a small difference. Here, my code uses *include* to get external language files, whereas in Viper-7's codepad, I use in-script functions.
Reason: Because I can't put/write files to codepad's system.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Davinder, this is the nice way to keep my data multilingual. But I want, tool tip of my new window should also comes in multilingual format.

Comment: could you provide us with a fiddle or some more explicit code?

Comment: @Sunil May we see the code you are using to produce your tooltip now? Be it jQuery, PHP, Javascript whichever language it is.

Comment: @Davinder - Thank you so much for your valuable comment.I got my problem resolved by creating my own customize window.I used jquery.window.js to create my own window.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `supplant`-method variant. Crockford wrote about such a thing [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html) and wrote it as an extension of `String`. It is essential a kind of templating:

```
if (!String.prototype.supplant) {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = o[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Regarding your problem, you could then use an object containing your translations:

```
var spanish = {close: "maximizar la ventana", thanks: "Gracias"};
var german  = {close: "Fenster schließen", thanks: "Danke"};
var english = {close: "Close window", thanks: "Thank you"};
```

and then use this on a string:

```
var spanish_message = "<a href='javascript:void(0);'>{close}</a>".supplant(spanish);

var german_message = "<a href='javascript:void(0);'>{close}</a>".supplant(german);
```

This is not jQuery, but works pretty well. However, you still need to identify the condition for which language to use yourself. I suggest using something on the server side, e.g. an extra param for the language to be used. If you have different windows of which you know, which is in which language you could also present the language-object used for each.

Also, if your translations become more complex, I suggest you put them in external js files.

lg,

flo